# Continuity Question- Suppose that f and g are continuous at a point c E R and g(c) = h(c). Define

Tags: calculus

Let $g$ and $h$ be functions defined on all of $\mathbb R$. Suppose that $f, g$ are continuous at a
point $c$ in $\mathbb R$ and $g(c) = h(c)$. Define

$f(x)$ =
      $ g(x)$, if $x  \leq c $ ;

$f(x)= h(x)$, if $x \geq c $.

Prove that $f$ is also continuous at $c$.

Comment: hi, I did some editing, I hope it's O.K with you. But I could not figure out the definition of $f$. Do you mean $x=c$?

Comment: @user99680 hi sorry, i meant g(x) if x <= c and h(x) >= c

Comment: you can use \geq with the  tags, for >= , \leq for <= , and \mathbb  tag for the Reals. Just wrap everything with  tags.

Comment: Try this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma for the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^-}g(x)=g(c)=f(c)$

$\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^+}h(x)=h(c)=f(c)$

Since $g(c)=h(c)$, $\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=f(c)$.

so $f$ is continuous.